# Loop em um Objeto com uma variável array

Tags: java, android

```
    {
        List<PedidosPendentesOBJ> listaPedidos = new ArrayList<>();
        List<ProdutosPendentes> produtosList = null;

        JSONObject o = new JSONObject(ret);
        JSONArray ts = o.names();

        for (int i = 0; i < ts.length(); i++) {

            String token = ts.getString(i);
            JSONObject p = o.getJSONObject(token);
            String cliente = p.getString("Cliente");

            JSONArray Produtos = p.getJSONArray("Produtos");

            for (int ii = 0; ii < Produtos.length(); ii++) {
                // ESSE ARRAY DEVE SER CHAMADO COMO NOVO, TODA VEZ QUE PASSAR NO LOOP
                produtosList = new ArrayList<>();
                JSONObject objPro = Produtos.getJSONObject(ii);
                String descricao = objPro.getString("descricao");
                double valor = objPro.getDouble("valor");
                produtosList.add(new ProdutosPendentes(descricao, valor, quanti));
            }
            // AQUI EU ADICIONO NA LISTA, QUE CADA OBJETO DEVERIA TER SUA VARIÁVEL DIERENTE CADA UM
            listaPedidos.add(new PedidosPendentesOBJ(token, cliente, valorTotal, status, data, produtosList));
        }
        return listaPedidos;
    }
```

Estou populando um `ArrayList` com vários Objetos com estrutura `for`. No entanto uma das variáveis é um array, ai que está o problema, quando o loop passa pelo Objeto ele entra no loop da variável array, e ao invés de ele criar um array lista para cada objeto, ele cria apenas uma e adiciona em todos os objetos na mesma lista de array.

Quero criar uma nova lista de array do objeto cada vez que o loop passar pelo objeto.

Comment: Você poderia limpar um pouco o código e deixar somente o que é necessário para resolver o problema?

Comment: Editei e tentei colocar o menor possível, obrigado pelo feedback

Comment: `produtosList = new ArrayList<>();` deveria ficar antes do loop, pelo que eu entendi do que você quer.

Comment: EU CONSEGUI. Obrigado a todos! A Resolução foi a seguinte: Eu estava usando dos Adapters diferente, então isso estava causando erro na hora de popular a Lista, então mudei para outro Adapter e resolveu o problema, tive apenas que mudar o **new ArrayList<>()** para fora do segundo loop.

Answer (score 2):

Pelo que entendi disso, você tá criando um array com apenas 1 objeto sempre.

Coloque `produtosList = new ArrayList<>();` antes do seu segundo loop, desse jeito vc cria uma list de produtos quando passar pelo segundo loop.